# Is it possible to access and list files of local system in web browser.

Tags: html

My requirement is to show a panel where I list the local system directory, from where I drag and drop the files inorder to perform operations on it.
In HTML5 the FileSystem API is available , but most of the browsers are not supporting.

Is it possible by using input type as file? Like we browse and select a directory, then we can see the list of files and their details?

Comment: Nope. That would be a huge security hole.

Comment: ...This seems like all I'll advised system. Why not use FTP?

Comment: Also by local to you mean client local or server local?

Comment: Not even possible using html5? My idea is to select a folder, list the files in it along with details like size and last modified date

Comment: Actually it is possible with Internet Explorer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the previous commenters correctly noted, this is not possible because it is considered a security hole. Think about a malicious script that could read out everything on your local file system just by visiting a web page.

You can however implement file drag-and-drop like this: https://github.com/moxiecode/plupload

Comment: Again, Is there any alternative other than html5?